# XML or JSON in SAPUI5 POST-request?

Tags: json, xml, http-headers, xmlhttprequest, sapui5

I am trying to post data to an SAP Backend System via an OData-Rest-API. There are a couple of tutorials online on how do that that also provide code samples. What confuses me is the specification of the "Content-Type" in the request header vs the data format in which the request data is actually offered. One code example is from [this site](http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2012/06/06/sample-ume-application-using-sapui5-and-sap-gateway--part-ii):

```
    OData.request({  
        requestUri:  "http://gwserver:8000/sap/opu/odata/sap/Z_UI5_USER_MAINT_CM/z_ui5_user_maintCollection",  
        method: "POST",  
        headers: {   
                   "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",  
                   "Content-Type": "application/atom+xml",  
                   "DataServiceVersion": "2.0",   
                   "Accept": "application/atom+xml,application/atomsvc+xml,application/xml",  
                   "X-CSRF-Token": header_xcsrf_token  
                  },  
        data:{  
                              username: username_var,  
                              title:title_var,  
                              title_p:title_var,  
                              firstname: firstname_var,  
                              lastname: lastname_var,  
                              password: password_var,  
                              department: department_var,  
                              language: language_var,  
                              telephone: telephone_var,  
                              e_mail: email_var,  
                              city: city_var,  
                              country: country_var,  
                              comm_type:"",  
                              fullname:"",  
                              userid:"",  
                              name:"",  
                              islocked:"",  
                              region: ""  
}},
```

Now what exactly is the format of "data" in this request? It does not look like XML. This leads to my next question, which is how to format the data of my POST-request. This is code from my web app's controller.js file:

```
         OData.request({
         requestUri: "proxy/http/XXXXXXXXX/sap/opu/odata/XXXXXXXXX",
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
                "Content-Type": "application/atom+xml",
                "DataServiceVersion": "2.0",
                "MaxDataServiceVersion": "2.0",
                "Pragma": "no-cache",
                "Cache-Control": "no-store, no-cache",                  
                "Accept": "application/atom+xml,application/atomsvc+xml,application/xml",       
                "X-CSRF-Token": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"                    
            },
            data: reqData
            },              
            function(data, response){
                alert('Done POSTing.');                     
            },
            function(err){                  
                console.log(err);                   
            });
```

I get a working X-CSRF-Token from a GET-request conducted with DHC REST client. Posting to the SAP system via DHC works without problems. 
What data format shall I store in the reqData variable? I tried assigning a string of the original XML to reqData, but it returns the error message
`no handler for data`. The XML data of one entry of my collection is structured as follows:

```
 <content type="application/xml">
        <m:properties>
            <d:Name m:type="PatientService.PersonName">
                <d:Family>Test10</d:Family>
                <d:First>Test10</d:First>
                <d:Prefix/>
            <d:Title/>
                <d:Affix/>
            </d:Name>
            <d:Gender>Female</d:Gender>
            <d:BirthDate m:null="true"/>
            <d:isActive>false</d:isActive>
            <d:NationalityISO>DE</d:NationalityISO>
            <d:BirthCountryISO>DE</d:BirthCountryISO>
            <d:BirthPlace>Hintertupfing</d:BirthPlace>
            <d:BirthName/>
        </m:properties>
    </content>
```

I have tried around five different XML to JSON converters to convert the XML content, it keeps throwing format errors like

```
DOMException: Failed to execute 'createElementNS' on 'Document': The    qualified name provided ('d:_m:type') contains multiple colons.(…)
```

And storing my data in an object like this:

```
{                       
                        Family: "Test10",
                        First: "Anna10",
                        Nationality: "DE",
                        BirthCountry: "DE",
                        BirthPlace: "Hintertupfing"
                        }
```

did not work either.

Answer (score 1):

why do you write your requests manuel?

```
//insert request
var oDataJSON = {
    "Name": {"Family": "Schultz", "First": "Mandy"},
    "Gender": "Female",
    "isActive": true
}
oDataModel.insert(oDataJSON);

//merge request
oDataJSON = {
    "Name": {"Family": "Schultz", "First": "Mandy"},
    "isActive", false
};
oDataModel.update(oDataJSON);
```

Now you can analyse the POST Requests e.g. with Chrome Developer Tools

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [dataJS documentation for this method](http://datajs.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=datajs%20OData%20API&referringTitle=OData%20Payload%20Formats#OData.request):

> The data property defines the payload of the request defined in the intermediate format. The request is passed as input to the handler object which serializes the request payload to the appropriate wire format; as controlled by the request headers. The transformed data is then stored in the body property. Finally, the modified request object is passed to the underlying network stack.

The way I understand it, then, the `data` parameter needs to be a list of key-value pairs, as shown in the example above. When the request is sent, the `OData.request` method will serialize this data in the format specified in the header.

Comment: The question that remains is how to format those key-value pairs in order to  construct a request body that exactly matches the requirements specified by the receiving service. There has to be some special syntax that allows generation of the kind of nested XML that is POSTed to the backend. Any ideas or documentation links? I cannot find anything on that topic.

Comment: no possibility to test if it works right now. but if i understand you correctly, it is sufficient to provide keys that match the XML-definitions and the data will automatically be arranged in the required nested way?

Comment: Yes, that is my understanding of it. Please do test it and let me know how it works.

Comment: The formatting of the payload is incorrect. The nested XML structure is not created properly.

Answer (score 0):

I got the formatting correct. The nested XML structure in the payload is achieved by nesting the data in the request specification like this:

```
data: {
        Name: {Family: "Schultz", First: "Mandy"}
      }
```

Comment: So in order to receive a json response, you have to send a json request in the first place?